# return different generic type via function's optional argument in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

### Background

I want to implement my own usePromise, e.g.

```
  // if with filterKey(e.g `K=list`), fileNodes's type should be `FileNode`  (i.e. T[K])
  const [fileNodes, isOk] = usePromise(
    () => {
      return Promise.resolve({list:[]}) as Promise<{ list: FileNode[] }>;
    },
    { initValue: [] },
    "list",
  );

  // if with no filterKey, data's type should be `{list: FileNode[]}`  (i.e. T)
  const [data, isOk] = usePromise(
    () => {
      return Promise.resolve({list:[]}) as Promise<{ list: FileNode[] }>;
    },
    { initValue: {list:[]} }
  );
```

### My problem

I use `K extends keyof T` to check `filterKey` and its type `K`

1. If K is property of T, it shuld return `T[K]`
2. If K is not property of T, it shuld return `T`

Here is the code which implements `usePromise`. **I found that `K extends keyof T` always result in false**.

How to fix my code?

```
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'

interface Options<T> {
  initValue?: T
  onError?: (r: () => any) => any
}
interface FileNode {}

export function usePromise<T, K>(
  factory: () => Promise<T>,
  options: Options<K extends keyof T ? T[K] : T> = {},
  filterKey?: K,
): [K extends keyof T ? T[K] : T, boolean] {
  type R = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : T;
  const [state, setState] = useState<R>(
    options.initValue!,
  );
  const isLoadingRef = useRef(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    factory().then((r) => {
      if (filterKey) {
        setState((r as any)[filterKey] as unknown as R);
      } else {
        setState(r as unknown as R);
      }
    }).catch((res) => {
      if (options.onError) options.onError(res);
      else throw res;
    });
  }, []);
  return [state, isLoadingRef.current] as [R, boolean];
}
```

### Complex solution

There is a complex solution via overloaded function. Is there any simple way?

```
export function usePromise<T, K extends keyof T>(
  factory: () => Promise<T>,
  options: Options<T[K]>,
  filterKey: K,
): [K extends keyof T ? T[K] : T, boolean];
export function usePromise<T>(
  factory: () => Promise<T>,
  options: Options<T>,
): [T, boolean];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current implementation of `usePromise` infers `K` to be `string | undefined` when you are expecting `'list'`. You can fix this by constraining the type of `K`:

```ts
export function usePromise<T, K extends keyof T | undefined>
```

Here is a minimal reproduction in a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN0A0KGASugGZFroCi556AxvAL5zlQQhwDkU6OZjwBQw4ADt8UcoPRwA8mBjAI41AB4AKgD5EwuHAnAYANRwAbZOgD8ALjib9cVTSicoduAAoo9rwEo4AF5dHHEAT0CQuDDw4RZRCSkZRjkAMWBzdAA5CAATOQQE4XQAD0hYdmRxZhVxYnQABU4QYAwtIgBpODL8cTzUOABrdHCIcgc4AB8UfooJdDztLycUmGhwvyjdZq429C1tAicIJTrUe0VlVQ1u3vR%20wZGxic04awcAbU6AXTh7HTBRAsY4GciZKSdUaeTrHfz2b49Up9AbDUbjSYfTTfP4AogAIwgECyYT%20CCcMHCYDkJCBd2RD1RzwxbyxOP%20DgA3E5GDd4J9ULh8EQMDBsHh0H8gg1xfh1CRlk4DKdrmoAHRGUwWKwAQlBcH83IMvLU8DaABkIDg8hIAOZkCbS6gOrwycwYQ1Oah0BjMLwBYK6ckGMGCdZQcIBNUwAAWD39UG2ehDIeAE1dEPQUChkWTKZDotl6ATMUGsX8n3B5khoz%20OEG1SG4ggAHd6vW4CRPfm4Gx0O7Ckr84WhcWoKXZk3W%203Bl2jfmEimWP41Yw8IwYwn0Kgk8H82nvCrzmqXG5oIEjzcT%20JXO4fNvu-n%20xg4LHOC24PxUPODMv5yC4E%20H5H34GBkCgeoBVHIgLStG1xHtChV3A-hJDrQZPhIAkiRJcQfm5YoCkYcwcH4OATUFZwzhuS5qLUdQkDAexBSgO1e20UQ9wo-kqxyfJtxg1B5CGKUGl2VoMBWFMA2iPcU1A8D6nE-Y1S-YkADdiyQcw2hgBE-mXCdlPabTdPsDIslyAogPYn9e31AwkE1MxLHQfT7KHAAiHTBU8-VPWKPcAHogsMCYW2MGM4GbdhM2zUYiDyPAcB4QZKWpOBUBjCBkHMPI4HxOQAAMEB8vS4AsvjrJ%20FgioMLxgDVdA1QcfweT5QCktwQThNE6hjOLIcZKDIcDAUiC4AG1Ttw0rS4DK9zDI7AaGPmsyKsyKr0BslhtDskEhyc8RjBcqx7FMwVFt7JwAqAA).

Comment: In your example, the second return unions type like `const data: FileNode[] | {list: FileNode[];}`. Could let it return `{list:FileNode[]}` only?

Comment: @ahuigo Yeah, all you have to do is add a default for the generic parameter `K`: `K extends keyof T | undefined = undefined`, which would look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZj6Pm).